# How can I get an ID from the end of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract an ID from the URL using this code:

```
   preg_match_all('!\d+!', $slug, $matches);
```

However, if the url/slug is `domain.com/number-5-shirt-28723` it thinks that the ID is 5 rather than 28723

It works fine if there are no numbers at all.

How can I make sure the ID is from the very end of the string after the last - ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` makes you sure you reached the end of string, so you may try to modify your preg to:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+$/', $slug, $matches);
```